# Apollo GraphQL - How to get aggregate frontend response server side

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

Is there a way to get the aggregate response on the server before it gets sent back to the frontend?

I’ve attempted to pull this from the top level resolver query (waiting after it has grabbed the sub-graphs) but it doesn’t appear to actual populate the sub-graph objects (it only shows me the ID).

```
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        sifKeysDeep: async (_, { clientId, ids, state }, { dataSources }) => {
            // I would expect an await on this would result in the aggregate but it doesn't
            return dataSources.sifAPI.getKeysDeepById(clientId, ids, state);
        }
```

```
export const SifKeyDeep = `#graphql
  type SifKeyDeep {
    ...
    G0: SifOpt // I should get this object from the top query, but instead I get the ID only
```

Is there a hook on the server side that allows me to retrieve the fully loaded query (aggregate) result before being sent back to the client?

I’d like to cache the final result in my memory store.

I’m new to GraphQL so my terminology could be off. Let me know so I can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this figured out. You can create your own plugin which listens for `willSendResponse`.

```
const willSendResponsePlugin = {
async requestDidStart(requestContext) {
  console.log('Request started!');
  return {
    async willSendResponse(context: GraphQLRequestContext<BaseContext>) {
        if (context.response.body.kind == "single") {
            if (context.response.body.singleResult.data) {
                const data = context.response.body.singleResult.data;
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    },
    async willSendSubsequentPayload(context) {
        console.log(`Will send subsequent payload...`);
    }
  };
},
```

};

And add to your ApolloServer `plugins`:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    ...
    plugins: [willSendResponsePlugin]
```

Now you can listen for events right before they get sent back to the client.